# How can i make my Django API work for multiple users at the same time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, multithreading

I created a Django API,lets say that take two numbers as input and returns the sum as output.
I wanted my API to work even if i get multiple users request on the API.
Can i solve this issue using ThreadPooling? if not can you suggest any other methods to handle multiple user request at the same time.
Any kind of help will be really appreciated.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: If the users need to log in, you can separate by (authorized) users.

Comment: How are you serving your API? If you're just using runserver, you should look into using Gunicorn or a similar WSGI/ASGI framework to server the application

Comment: It'll be your server that handles multiple requests. Django can already be hooked-in to that server with ASGI (asynchronous), so that should be fine.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

views.py:

```
class DConfig(APIView):
def get(self, request):
    emp2 = device_config.objects.all()
    serializer = device_configSerializer(emp2, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def post(self, request, format=None):
    serializer = device_configSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

urls:

```
path('MDT', views.MDT.as_view()),
path('DConfig', views.DConfig.as_view()),
```

Like this you want to create the API if your project is Hosted in server then any one can use this api via urls

Comment: Hello! Could you provide more context to your answer? What are `APIView`, `DConfig`, `device_config`, `device_configSerializer`...? As of now, we can't understand and use your answer.

Comment: @bastantoine exactly what you want to do tell me that i will tell you

Comment: Please provide more context to your answer. If I copy-paste your code in a program of mine, I will need to make a lot of changes to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Django is by default sync framework - runs on gunicorn, if you need it to run asynchronously...

You will need to install uvicorn, thats an asynchronous web server for django https://www.uvicorn.org/

you will probably also need to do some reading on the async architecture - mainly for dajngo.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/async/

You can also refer to my https://github.com/Lum1naT/async_django_api - the svelte client does not work - but the entire project runs on DRF and is dockerized - read the README.md